# Failed to load C++/CLI bridge dll in .net application after VS2012 porting

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, porting

I am porting my solution from VS2010 to VS2012. All the core logic was implemented in C++ and the .net modules access these features through managed wrapper(C++/CLI bridge).

At the customer site, one of my wrapper dll is failed to load by their project with an error "Failed to load dll, one more dependent modules not found". But all the dependent dlls available in the machine. The same dll is successfully load from another .net test application I developed. What may be the possible reason for this ?

I found in an article that VS2012 have implemented 'Strict Platform Checking' so mixing AnyCPU and X64 builds might cause this error. I could reproduce this error in a test application. But in actual deployment all my projects are built in X64 platform in 64-bit machine.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562386/Lessons-learned-migrating-to-Visual-Studio-2012-an

Answer (score 0):

The C++ compiler automatically targets the latest .NET version, while C# and other languages try to preserve the .NET framework setting during upgrade.  So you get a mismatch.

The solution is to change the project settings for the non-C++ projects to target the same, newer .NET version.

Comment: During porting, all my .net projects target changed to 4.5 automatically. But the target of CLI projects framework shows 4.0 instead of 4.5. So I changed the target framework by manually editing the project settings using switch '<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>'.

Comment: Followed the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562386/Lessons-learned-migrating-to-Visual-Studio-2012-an

Comment: Thank you all for your response, finally I could solve this issue.

The problem was not the C++/CLI dll that failed to load !!!.
Application that failed to load my dll was using another ActiveX interop dll. This interop dll was not generated for VS2012, infact its an old version generated for VS2010. Hope MS will remove these kind of misleading message to make our life happier :)